# Flat Promise chain with dependencies and error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

How can I maintain a flat Promise chain when having dependencies on the results of previous Promise calls like this:

```
const authorize = function ({ user, allowAdmin, allowUser }) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (user.username === 'admin' && allowAdmin) {
      return resolve();
    }
    if (user.username === 'user' && !allowUser) {
      return reject(new Error('Unauthorized'));
    }
  });
};

const parse = function (value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (value < 10) {
      return resolve(value * 2)
    }
    else {
      return reject(new Error('Parser error'));
    }
  });
};

const validate = function (parsedValue) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const validationErrors = [];
    if (parsedValue > 16) {
      return reject(new Error('Validation error'));
    } else if (parsedValue > 8) {
      validationErrors.push({ result: 'value must be < 8' });
      return resolve(validationErrors);
    }
    else {
      return resolve(validationErrors);
    }
  });
};

const execute = function (validatedValue) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (validatedValue < 6) {
      return resolve(validatedValue)
    }
    else {
      return reject(new Error('Execution error'));
    }
  });
};

const handle = function (user, value) {
  authorize({ user, allowAdmin: true })
    .then(parse(value))
    .then(validate) // how to pass result of parse here without nesting?
    .then(execute) // how to pass result of validate without nesting?
    .then(console.log('done'))
    .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
};

handle({ username: 'admin'}, 9);
```

Comment: `.then(parse(value))` should be `.then(() => parse(value))` and there is nothing else you have to do. The promise returned by `.then` resolves to the value returned by the callback. So `.then(foo).then(bar)` passes the return value of `foo` to `bar`. Also, you don't have to make all these functions return promises if they don't perform async actions. They can just directly return their results.

Comment: What about your code as written isn't working?

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, this did the trick. I was returning promises in the sample because my real code returns promises as well. If you post your comment as answer I'm happy to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: First of all resolve and reject are not returned, they are just executed. You are not passing anything in resolve in authorize for it to be passed to next then. To pass data to a skip level then you can try one of the two options. Pass a value to a top-level variable and access it in all level of then or you can maintain a proper data structure which will be passed in each level. Something like `{value: val, errors: []}`